# C# Convert ReadOnlyMemory<byte> to byte[]

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

Given [ReadOnlyMemory Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.readonlymemory-1?view=netcore-3.1) I want to convert the stream into a string

I have the following code:

```
var body = ea.Body; //ea.Body is of Type ReadOnlyMemory<byte>
var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);
```

And it gives the following error. I am using the latest C# with .NET CORE 3.1

[image]

Which is funny because I am literally copy pasting the Hello World example [of a major product called RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-dotnet.html) and it doesn't compile.

Comment: I created an issue so that RabbitMQ can adapt the documentation: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-website/issues/963

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You cannot drop a thing that's read-only into a slot typed as `byte[]`, because `byte[]`s are writable and that would defeat the purpose. It looks like RabbitMQ [changed their API in February](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/commit/8bf93082fd2c18bbd6adff260d38a6fd34d6840b) and perhaps forgot to update the sample code.

A quick workaround is to use `.ToArray()`:

```cs
var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);
```

Edit: Since this was accepted, I'll amend it with the better solution posed by Dmitry and zenseb which is to use `.Span`:

```cs
var body = ea.Body.Span;
var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);
```

Comment: Note that the overload on GetString is not included in .Net Framework.

Answer (score 27):

Use [Span property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.readonlymemory-1.span?view=netcore-3.1) to convert message to string without additional memory allocation

```
var body = ea.Body; //ea.Body is of Type ReadOnlyMemory<byte>
var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body.Span);
Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);
```

Comment: Does using Span give a memory limitation e.g. only takes first 100 characters out of a 150 message?

Comment: You can use Span's Slice method to access any slice of the allocated memory region, by default Span returns all allocated region

Answer (score 14):

You need to use the `Span`property.

```
var data = new byte[] { 72, 101, 108, 108, 111 };
var body = new ReadOnlyMemory<byte>(data);
var text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body.Span);

Console.WriteLine(text);
```

`Encoding.UTF8.GetString` has an overload for `ReadOnlySpan<byte>`. You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getstring?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_Encoding_GetString_System_ReadOnlySpan_System_Byte__)

Answer (score 1):

I updated the RabbitMQ.Client package and had the same problem at my Consumer_Received method:

```cs
private static void Consumer_Received(object sender, BasicDeliverEventArgs e)
        // Code
```

I checked `BasicDeliverEventArgs` and saw that `Body` is now a ReadOnlyMemory type:
`public ReadOnlyMemory<byte> Body { get; set; }`

As Jeff said, [RabbitMQ changed their API](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/commit/8bf93082fd2c18bbd6adff260d38a6fd34d6840b), so I think this changed from previous tutorials we had on internet.

To fix, I only had to transform my Body message into a Array (into Consumer_Received method):
`var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Body.ToArray());`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and resolved using the following approach -

```
 public override void HandleBasicDeliver(string consumerTag, ulong deliveryTag, bool redelivered, string exchange, string routingKey, IBasicProperties properties, ReadOnlyMemory<byte> body) {
 var msg = body.ToArray();
 var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msg);
```